# How do I change the font of a UILabel in swift without changing the font size?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, label

I have programatically created a label which I have set the adjustsToFitWidth to true. Now I want to change its font, but I can't do that without making the font size of the label constant. Does anybody know how I could change only the font and not the font size of a UILabel in swift?

Comment: Just because you don't change the font size doesn't necessarily mean that two different fonts with the same text and same size will take up the same space.

Answer (score 39):

Why not get the font size, and specify a new font with this value ?

```
let fontSize = self.label.font.pointSize;
self.label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: fontSize)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: label.font.pointSize)
```

This will use the same font size, "Arial" can be whatever family you want to choose.

Answer (score 4):

An improved answer.

UILabel Subclassing: Add an empty swift file and name it. e.g..EZLabel. Add the following code.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class EZLabel: UILabel {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        changeFontName()
    }

    func changeFontName()
    {
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: self.font.pointSize)
    }
}
```

The advantage is that you don't need to change each UILabel's font in the whole project if needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UILabel {
    override open func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        changeFontName()
    }

    func changeFontName()
    {
        self.font = UIFont(name: "YOUR_FONT_NAME", size: self.font.pointSize)
    }
}

/* Do this also for buttons and any uiviews */
```

Comment: first : create a swift file then put that code above inside that file under the importing UIKIt section not Foundation and everyThing will work just fine after that just run your app and all the labels inside your app will take the font you just gave to them .